# Table schema for storing large number of location coordinates in database

Tags: postgresql, schema, postgis, large-data

I need to store a large number of location coordinates along with their timestamp. Here is how current table schema looks like:

```
User_ID, Location_Coordinate, Timestamp
```

Where each user is being tracked continuously and a lot of location coordinates would be generated for each user. There are multiple users. What would be the right way to store such data efficiently?

I would need to retrieve past 24 hours of data for each user.

Comment: Do you have any further need for the data after 24 hours? If so, how do you need to access the data older than 24 hours? How many users?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to store it all in a single table with a PostGIS `geometry` column for the location. What is "efficient" depends entirely on your application. There are a few things to consider:

- If you want to store each and every location of every user, use a regular table. Whether or not you should use indexes depends on the number of inserts (new locations being entered) and how you retrieve the data. Very frequent inserts means that the indexes have to be updated frequently; that is a performance penalty.
- If you get more locations than you need for your application (e.g. automatic pushing of the current location from a (GPS) device), then you might want to consider using an unlogged table without indexes (which is therefore very fast to insert) and then regularly poll that table for new records, process them (i.e. reduce number of locations to store only the relevant ones), and store the processed data permanently in another table with the appropriate indexes. There are many processing function in PostGIS that you could use for this purpose. Keep that unlogged table small (poll regularly and delete processed data) and you won't miss the indexes. You would then query this latter table for the past 24 hours and use the unlogged table only for newly received locations.

Otherwise, there is not much advice that can be given with the limited information that you supply. Edit your question with more details and you will get a more detailed answer.